# Generating rectilinear grid coordinates in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia, what's the best way to make an (X, Y) array like this?

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
0 1
1 1
2 1
3 1
0 2
1 2
2 2
3 2
0 3
1 3
2 3
3 3
```

Coordinates are regular and rectilinear but not necessarily integers.

Comment: is `vcat(([x y] for x in 0:3 for y in 0:3)...)` what you need?

Comment: Ah yes, that is concise and works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you want to use a lazy array for this instead of an array of numbers? Using an actual array here seems like MATLAB/R/Python bad habits.

Comment: Usually these numbers are arbitrary input. It just happens that one of my arbitrary inputs is a grid. So normally you couldn't write it as a lazy array anyway in my case. Also the actually array is only like 2x200 so I don't really care about a few bytes.

Comment: I just found [these examples](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/14be0dcf3908d2767cb40266d26068c416aadbf1/examples/ndgrid.jl) -- maybe they're useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Julia 0.6 includes an efficient `product` iterator which allows for a fourth solution. Comparing all solutions:

```
using Base.Iterators

f1(xs, ys) = [[xs[i] for i in 1:length(xs), j in 1:length(ys)][:] [ys[j] for i in 1:length(xs), j in 1:length(ys)][:]]
f2(xs, ys) = hcat(repeat(xs, outer=length(ys)), repeat(ys, inner=length(xs)))
f3(xs, ys) = vcat(([x y] for y in ys for x in xs)...)
f4(xs, ys) = (eltype(xs) == eltype(ys) || error("eltypes must match"); 
                reinterpret(eltype(xs), collect(product(xs, ys)), (2, length(xs)*length(ys)))')

xs = 1:3
ys = 0:4

@show f1(xs, ys) == f2(xs, ys) == f3(xs, ys) == f4(xs, ys)

using BenchmarkTools

@btime f1($xs, $ys)
@btime f2($xs, $ys)
@btime f3($xs, $ys)
@btime f4($xs, $ys)
```

On my PC, this results in:

```
f1(xs, ys) == f2(xs, ys) == f3(xs, ys) == f4(xs, ys) = true
  548.508 ns (8 allocations: 1.23 KiB)
  3.792 μs (49 allocations: 2.45 KiB)
  1.916 μs (51 allocations: 3.17 KiB)
  353.880 ns (8 allocations: 912 bytes)
```

For `xs = 1:300` and `ys=0:400` I get:

```
f1(xs, ys) == f2(xs, ys) == f3(xs, ys) == f4(xs, ys) = true
  1.538 ms (13 allocations: 5.51 MiB)
  1.032 ms (1636 allocations: 3.72 MiB)
  16.668 ms (360924 allocations: 24.95 MiB)
  927.001 μs (10 allocations: 3.67 MiB)
```

**Edit:**

By far the fastest method is a direct loop over a preallocated array:

```
function f5(xs, ys)
    lx, ly = length(xs), length(ys)
    res = Array{Base.promote_eltype(xs, ys), 2}(lx*ly, 2)
    ind = 1
    for y in ys, x in xs
        res[ind, 1] = x
        res[ind, 2] = y
        ind += 1
    end
    res
end
```

For `xs = 1:3` and `ys = 0:4`, `f5` takes `65.339 ns (1 allocation: 336 bytes)`.

For `xs = 1:300` and `ys = 0:400`, it takes `280.852 μs (2 allocations: 1.84 MiB)`.

**Edit 2:**

Including `f6` from Dan Getz' comment:

```
function f6(xs, ys)
    lx, ly = length(xs), length(ys)
    lxly = lx*ly
    res = Array{Base.promote_eltype(xs, ys), 2}(lxly, 2)
    ind = 1
    while ind<=lxly
        @inbounds for x in xs
            res[ind] = x
            ind += 1
        end
    end
    for y in ys
        @inbounds for i=1:lx
        res[ind] = y
        ind += 1
        end
    end
    res
end
```

By respecting the column-major order of Julia arrays, it reduces the timings to `47.452 ns (1 allocation: 336 bytes)` and `171.709 μs (2 allocations: 1.84 MiB)`, respectively.

Comment: Squeezing a bit more from `f5`, [github gist of `f6`](https://gist.github.com/getzdan/aa287ce691673d40c9f953dfc23ad038)

Comment: `Julia 1.7` here: `f4`, `f5`, `f6` give me errors. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick. Not sure it is the best solution though. Seems a bit convoluted.

```
xs = 0:3;
ys = 0:3;
out = [[xs[i] for i in 1:length(xs), j in 1:length(ys)][:] [ys[j] for i in 1:length(xs), j in 1:length(ys)][:]]
```

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a job for [repeat](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/linalg.html#Base.repeat):
`hcat(repeat(0:3, outer=4), repeat(0:3, inner=4))`.

Note that, it's way too slower than array comprehension when `xs` or `ys` is small(e.g. `3`,`30`).